# How to delete individual column indices of a tibble?

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr, tibble

I have a `tidyverse::tibble` which I produced from prior calculations. Unfortunately, my columns have different indices and given that I want to transform the tibble using `tidyr::pivot_longer()`, executing the latter gives me the error `Error in rbind.zoo(...) : indexes overlap` . At least I presume this, as I have tried to fix it in many ways now.

Therefore: How do I delete the indices of the different columns which are currently still dates and have been taken over from early calculations? I don't need them anymore.

Executing `str()` on my tibble (still named .df, sry) gives me:

[image]

I do not really care what the indices are. As far as I am concerned, they can all be num 1:20 (I have 20 rows in the original tibble that I want to `tidyr::pivot_longer()`).

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Thank you Ronak. Since I do not know myself at which point in my code these column indices were set (the dates) I can not reliably reproduce the error. Also, I do not know how to set individual column indices, so this is unfortunately not an option to me. I am hoping that somebody knows of a simple function or way to delete column indices in a tibble.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know whether this will help other people with the same problem in the future, but:

When constructing your tibble or data.frame prior to pivot_longer(), filling the columns by converting the input to a vector before putting them in the columns worked for me. It "deleted" or at least did not take over the indices.